# How do you log content of a JSON object in Node.js?

Tags: json, node.js

Is it possible to print an objects contents e.g. methods and attributes in Node.js?

At the moment I'm trying to print the session object and get the following:

```
console.log("Session:" + session);
> Session:[object Object]
```

Maybe in a similar way to print_r(array) in PHP, or using .toString in Java.

Comment: `console.log("Session:" + util.inspect(session))`

Comment: For a more intuitive and visual output of objects take a look at nodedump: https://github.com/ragamufin/nodedump

Answer (score 305, accepted):

Try this one:

```
console.log("Session: %j", session);
```

If the object could be converted into JSON, that will work.

Comment: I am trying to do this for the request object but it shows error TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
Is there any way to limit the depth

Comment: anyway to pretty print this?

Comment: @chovy: something like this might work: console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4));

Comment: this worked for me: `console.log("Session: %O", session);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console

Comment: this this console.log no fuss drop-in replacement https://www.npmjs.com/package/console-log-json

Answer (score 154):

```
function prettyJSON(obj) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
}

// obj -> value to convert to a JSON string
// null -> (do nothing)
// 2 -> 2 spaces per indent level
```

[JSON.stringify on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 33):

To have an output more similar to the raw `console.log(obj)` I usually do use `console.log('Status: ' + util.inspect(obj))` (JSON is slightly different).

Comment: This gives "util is not defined".  You must `var util = require("util") first.  Also, the sub-objects still turn out as [Object] and not the JSON string that represents them.

Comment: To remove the depth limit, use: `require('util').inspect(obj, {depth:null})`

Answer (score 30):

This will work with any object:

```
    var util = require("util");
    console.log(util.inspect(myObject, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
```

Comment: This works great for error objects. None of their properties show up in the other solutions.

Comment: This just hangs for me. I think circular references in an object crashes it

Comment: @Richard it probably hang(ed) for you due to the depth option being set to `null`. Inspect has built-in treatment for circular references.

Answer (score 7):

console.dir() is the most direct way.

Comment: console.dir(someJsonObject); still leaves nested objects unprinted, for me.

Comment: I think it won't drill into objects through their prototype and it won't deal with certain recursion. You're either going to have to do something like console.log(JSON.stringify()) or something more specific to your object if .dir() isn't sufficient. If you have more info about the object, perhaps more specific advice can be given.

Comment: It can take the same options as util.inspect. Add {depth:null}

Comment: I like the formatting (a nice compromise between readability and compactness) but be warned that this does not output valid JSON:

 * single quotes around strings

 * object keys are not quoted if they're words

Answer (score 2):

[console.dir](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/dir) with the depth argument set will do the trick. This will print JSON objects to any arbitrary depth.  Depth:null means print every level.

```
console.dir(someObject, { depth: null })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(obj);
```

Run: node app.js > output.txt

Answer (score 0):

This will for most of the objects for outputting in nodejs console

```js
var util = require('util')
function print (data){
  console.log(util.inspect(data,true,12,true))
  
}

print({name : "Your name" ,age : "Your age"})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for some options, there is a NPM package that might help you, a drop-in replacement for console.log called [console-log-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/console-log-json).  The nice thing about it is that it will create consistent JSON formatted logs, despite the fact that you can throw at console.log() any number of parameters in any order, including other JSON objects as well as Error objects and plain strings.

It also handles automatically adding some extra helpful attributes such as time stamps and file where the console.log() was called from, etc..

[image: example JSON output]

These all get printed to STDOUT so any log shipping and aggregator can pick it up and parse the JSON.