# Convert [object Object] from to value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Using the code below I want to find the value in the field seq for the row where _id=user:

```
DbModels.prototype.autoIncrement = function(_collection, callback){
  this.getCollection(_collection, function(error, seq_collection) {
  if( error ) callback(error)
      else {
        console.log(seq_collection);
        seq_collection.find({_id: 'Users'}, {'seq': 1}, function(error, result) {
                if( error ) callback(error)
                else {callback(null, result)}
              });
    }
  });
}

DbModels.prototype.addUser = function(Users, callback) { 

  this.autoIncrement("seq", function(error, result){
    if(error) callback(error);
                else console.log("RESULT: "+result);ID=result;
  });
```

The code is working properly, however the results is "RESULT: [object Object]" and I have no idea how I can convert [object Object] to a value in nodejs.

When I run the query in the mongo shell the output  is: {"_id":"Users","seq":51}

Anyone any suggestions?

Comment: Which monogodb binding are you using?  Can you link to the homepage for the docs?

Comment: MongoDB: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Developer+Zone

And for nodejs I am using: 
https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native

Comment: try logging like this: `console.log("RESULT:"); console.log(result); ID=result;` and see if that vaguely gives what youw ant.

Comment: `console.log('RESULT:', result);`

Answer (score 2):

It is a value (specifically a reference to an object).  It only looks like that when you call `toString` (implicitly because of the concatenation).  You probably want to look at the docs and see what the relevant fields and methods are for `result`.

From [these docs](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/docs/queries.md), it looks like you might want to process the result a little differently:

```
seq_collection.find({_id: 'Users'}, {'seq': 1}).toArray(function(err, results){
    console.log(results); // output all records
});
```

Comment: Using 'else console.log(result.toString());ID=result;' also gives [object Object]

Comment: You're doing the same thing, calling `toString`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
console.log("RESULT: "+JSON.stringify(result));
```

It should print the contents of the result.

On response to the comment (missing formatting in comment):

Try this in a node console:

```
> o = {a:13}
{ a: 13 }
> o['c'] = o
{ a: 13, c: [Circular] }
> JSON.stringify(o)
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at repl:1:7
    at REPLServer.eval (repl.js:80:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:182:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:162:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:426:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:603:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:82:12)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:88:20)
```

Comment: That gives the following result:
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at c:\Program Files\nodejs\DbModels.js:192:50
    at c:\Program Files\nodejs\DbModels.js:182:23
    at Collection.find (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\collection.js:698:5)
    at c:\Program Files\nodejs\DbModels.js:180:24
    at c:\Program Files\nodejs\DbModels.js:63:10
    at [object Object].collection (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:320:44)
    at [object Object].getCollection (c:\Program Files\nodejs\DbModels.js...

Comment: It looks like you have a circular reference in your data. I have updated the answer - to get the formatting.

Comment: I'm quite certain OP doesn't grok what that means torben.

Comment: @torbenl, `results` clearly isn't pure data.  It has self-references, and probably methods too.  So it's not appropriate for either `stringify` or `toString`.

Comment: Maybe you could try to do the find in the 'mongo' shell?

Comment: @torbenl, presumably he'll have similar issues when he needs to do something real.  He needs to find a way to query where he can understand the data model of the response.  As is, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: That was exactly my point - try to do the `find` in a 'mongo' shell, to see what constitutes the response.

Comment: The output in the mongo shell is: {"_id":"Users","seq":51}

Comment: Take a look at one of the threads about printing a JavaScript object e.g. [Print content of JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625208/print-content-of-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1):

I think, this is the answer:
[How do you log content of a JSON object in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428235/how-to-print-json-object-content-in-node-js)

The easiest way is:

```
this.autoIncrement("seq", function(error, result){
    if(error) callback(error);
              else console.log("RESULT: %j",result);ID=JSON.stringify(result);
});
```

Comment: seems that has already been suggested. also i think the OP wants the `seq` field so `ID` should probably set to that specifically instead of the whole result object.