# (object Object) returning from JSON request in Node

Tags: javascript, json, http, node.js

I have another simple question about Node. I'm trying to make a simple http request to the Open Courseware search API (http://www.ocwsearch.com/api), but I'm running into some problems actually parsing the JSON... which normally hasn't been a problem.
The request returns a string that has escaped characters and slashes, and so I've run a replace and an unescape on the response string, but this ends up returning something like '[object Object]'. Right now, all I really want to do is be able to SEE what's finally being returned, so I can tell whether or not I can finally parse it as valid JSON. Unfortunately, this is not working either. I've read a couple of similar threads on stack overflow, but I'm still unable to get it to work.

What I've tried:

- iterating over the object being passed, because I thought it'd be something with key value pairs, and running over it, logging it each time. However, this prints it out as a string:

[

o

b

...
  all the way to the end (])

Given x as the returned formatted object in question,

- using "" + x, toString(), to try to convert it to a string
- using console.log("%j", x) as per [How do you log content of a JSON object in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428235/how-to-print-json-object-content-in-node-js)

None of these seem to work though, they're all returning me [object Object].

I've even tried it in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S47QL/2/
I'm replacing console.log with alert, and it seems to be re

My code:

```
var request = require('request');$
request('http://www.ocwsearch.com/api/v1/search.json?q=' + skill +     '&contact=http%3a%2f%2fwww.ocwsearch.com%2fabout/',$
  function(error, response, body){$
  if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){~$
      console.log(response.toString().replace(/\\\//g, "/"));$
        var x = response.toString().replace(/\\\//g, "/");$
        console.log(x)$
        console.log(x.keys());$
  }$  
});$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right now, all I really want to do is be able to SEE what's finally being returned, so I can tell whether or not I can finally parse it as valid JSON.

So then make the request in a browser window (using Chrome you can see the actual results being returned in the inspector tabs - press F12).

Example: http://www.ocwsearch.com/api/v1/search.json?q=ios&contact=http%3a%2f%2fwww.ocwsearch.com%2fabout/

And according to http://jsonlint.com/ this is valid JSON being returned. Are you *sure* you're not trying to be too smart for your own good?

You can't write the response to string, because it's an object. You need the data returned, but I think the body field does what you want. Have you tried just printing `body`?

Comment: you could also loop over the keys in body, and see what that prints out (`for (var k in body){ console.log(k) }`)

Comment: Ack, I was being silly. Working late in the night I sometime replaced "body" with "response"... I probably should have been more clear, when I try to print the json being returned, it gets printed with a large amount of escape slashes on the server (it was escaping the original escape sequences. For example, it was returning "http:\\/\\/..."). I was trying to remove them because it wasn't allowing me to just call the attributes directly, even though I put them directly into the browser and it looked fine.  Also, above I posted that I was unable to just loop over it, although I think that this

Comment: was just me being tired at night and not realizing that I somewhere in between changed the "body" variable to "response", which wasn't returning me anything...

Comment: *wasn't returning me what I wanted to see
And yup... that was the problem.. all I had to do was run everything on body instead, and then run JSON.parse() on it. Stupid of me... Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out :D