# How to send the 'FIN' with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Update:** I posted this code here, after I added all (to 99%) possibilities one by one, and it still gave me a 120sec timeout...buffled.

---

So, ok, I figured it takes exactly 120sec (ok, 122sec) on my Windows 7 machine, until the `FIN` handshake is started. I want to do it immediately. [HTTP RFC793](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) says

> FIN:  No more data from sender

Looks to me I do not send any data anymore. I tried all this bloated code, still a `Hello World` server...

```
var http = require('http')
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
    res.write('HELLO WORLD!\n')
    res.end()
    res.setTimeout(0)
    req.abort()     // 1) TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'abort'

    req.on('socket', function (socket) {
        socket.setTimeout(0)  
        socket.on('timeout', function() {
            req.abort()
        })
    })
})
server.timeout = 0
server.setTimeout(0)
server.listen(1337, '192.168.0.101')
```

1. So how to do 1) ?  (Actually sends a `RST` like this...)
2. And how to do the whole thing `HTTP` conform?
   Of course in the end I will be lucky to use `nodejs` as in `websocket` stuff and all this, but if conversion on my website means a thing of two minutes, and I have a million concurrent users (huh?), sending a `FIN` immediately could mean I have two million concurrent users (do the math). ;) Ok, to be on the sure side: Sending a `FIN` means the socket is closed?
3. Ah, eah, ok, since you are on, how do I `console.log(res)` or `console.log(req)`? It gives me `[object Object]`. (Update: I tried `console.log(res.toSource())`, gives me a `TypeError`?
   **Edit:** Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428235/how-to-print-json-object-content-in-node-js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to close the connection, send a `connection: close` header.  If you do this, then it will not leave the connection open for reuse.

Comment: Thank you sir! So the default time of 120secs is not changeable, when I look at my trials?

Comment: setTimeout(0) removes the timeout entirely.  setTimeout(1) would make it 1ms.

Comment: Hmm, I still had 2 minutes timeout with all that `0`s. :/ Did not try out anymore on the weekend , was into parallax scrolling haha. Which `setTimeout` do you exactly mean?

Comment: Keep in mind, this may not be what you want.  If this is running live handling multiple connections from the same host the keep-alive will help performance since http requests won't require a new socket to be established.

Comment: Hey @jeremy. Just saw your comment now. Yeah, I wanted to be prepared for the task to finish off certain connections ( like a doorguard ;). In the end I found that: `res.end()` does the job alone ( and sends the header ).